# Why sum function is slower if the 'start' argument is an instance of custom class?

Tags: python, python-3.x, optimization, cpython, python-3.11

I was playing around with `sum` function and observed the following behaviour.

*case 1:*

```
source = """
class A:
    def __init__(self, a):
        self.a = a
    
    def __add__(self, other):
        return self.a + other;

sum([*range(10000)], start=A(10))
"""

import timeit
print(timeit.timeit(stmt=source))
```

As you can see I am using an instance of custom class as `start` argument to the `sum` function. Benchmarking above code takes around `192.60747704200003` seconds in my system.

*case 2:*

```
source = """
class A:
    def __init__(self, a):
        self.a = a
    
    def __add__(self, other):
        return self.a + other;

sum([*range(10000)], start=10).  <- Here
"""

import timeit
print(timeit.timeit(stmt=source))
```

But if I remove the custom class instance and use `int` object directly it tooks only `111.48285191600007` seconds. I am curious to understand the reason for this speed difference?

*My system info:*

```
>>> import platform
>>> platform.platform()
'macOS-12.5-arm64-arm-64bit'
>>> import sys
>>> sys.version
'3.11.0 (v3.11.0:deaf509e8f, Oct 24 2022, 14:43:23) [Clang 13.0.0 (clang-1300.0.29.30)]'
```

Comment: Adding two ints can be done in a single CPU instruction. Calling a method to add two integers together requires more computation

Comment: @byxor But `A(10) + 0` returns an `int` and not an instance of `A` (`return self.a + other`). So at first glance the method is just called once, and that shouldn't make such a difference?

Comment: @byxor Adding two ints in Python is much more than one CPU instruction, Python is not C. Anyway, the `__add__` method gets called only once, for the first addition, then we only add integers and are in the same situation as the first example. The main difference comes from having to create and initialize the `A(10)` instance, which one can see by using a `range(0)`. Using a `range(1)` will add the time needed for the first addition, which is the second largest reason for the second code being slower.

Comment: Yes, the only point I'm making is that case 2 doesn't require as much computation (and generally runs faster), regardless of the python implementation

Comment: @ThierryLathuille I don't think that creating an initializing one A is the main difference. The main reason is that the custom type for `start` causes the builtin sum to miss a CPython fast-path optimization.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[builtin_sum_impl](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Python/bltinmodule.c) has 2 implementations inside, one if the `start` is a number which skips creating python "number objects" and just sums numbers in C.

the other slower implementation when `start` is not a number, which forces the `__add__` method of "number objects" to be called, (because it assumes you are summing some weird classes).

you forced it to use [the slower one](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/27d8dc2c9d3de886a884f79f0621d4586c0e0f7a/Python/bltinmodule.c#L2478-L2481).

Answer (score -1):

Maybe looking at the byte-code can help understand what happens. If you run

```
import dis

def test_range():
    class A:
        def __init__(self, a):
            self.a = a

        def __add__(self, other):
            return self.a + other

    sum([*range(10000)], start=10)

dis.dis(test_range)
```

the version with `start=A(10)` generates 2 more instructions:

```
2 LOAD_CONST               1 (<code object A at 0x7ff0bfa25c90, file "/.../main.py", line 5>)
...
26 LOAD_CONST               4 (10)
28 LOAD_CONST               5 (('start',))
30 CALL_FUNCTION_KW         2
32 POP_TOP
34 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
36 RETURN_VALUE
```

vs

```
2 LOAD_CONST               1 (<code object A at 0x7ff0bfa25c90, file "/.../main.py", line 5>)
...
26 LOAD_FAST                0 (A)       <--- here
28 LOAD_CONST               4 (10)
30 CALL_FUNCTION            1           <--- and here
32 LOAD_CONST               5 (('start',))
34 CALL_FUNCTION_KW         2
36 POP_TOP
38 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
40 RETURN_VALUE
```

Complete byte-code for version with `start=A(10)` is [here](https://gist.github.com/markopacak/0855497dc95f3b8508e74552883f0dcb).

My (limited) understanding is that those 2 lines point to the initialization of `A`. Please, someone confirm.

Comment: This is not the reason. A couple of ops in the disassembly is not going to make a meaningful difference. All of the calculation happens inside that one CALL_FUNCTION_KW op, which is referring to the builtin [sum](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum).